# How Auto Wire byType sets the bean in Spring?

Tags: spring

Here is my `applicationContext.xml` configuration

```
<bean name="foo" 
      class="com.bmc.repository.HibernateCustomerRepositoryImpl">
</bean>

<bean name="customerService" class="com.bmc.service.CustomerServiceImpl" autowire="byType">
</bean>
```

Java Code:

```
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public void setFoo(CustomerRepository b) {
        this.customerRepository = b;
    }
}
```

The customerService bean has dependency on HibernateCustomerRepositoryImpl.

So my questions are:

> **1.** How spring will bind the HibernateCustomerRepositoryImpl bean with CustomerService? using setter method ?
>
> **2.** If yes, What should be the name of Method? should it be setPropertyName or setBeanName ?
>
> **3.** How Spring will find the setter method? using matching argument type ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean name="foo" id="foo" 
      class="com.bmc.repository.HibernateCustomerRepositoryImpl">
</bean>
<bean name="customerService" class="com.bmc.service.CustomerServiceImpl" autowire="byType">
    <property name="foo" ref="foo"></property>
</bean>
```